# no network access in /etc/network/if-up.d script

Tags: linux, networking, ssh-tunnel, raspbian, debian-stretch

I have a raspberry pi behind a NAT and a remote virtual server.
I want to be able to access the pi via remote shell from outside.

To achieve this I created an executable file `/etc/network/if-up.d/ssh_tunnel` on the pi containing

```
sudo -u myname ssh -fCNR *:2222:localhost:22 myname@1.2.3.4
```

While this command works, when executed as root from the command line, it doesn't work on startup.

Redirecting stderr to a file gives me

```
ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.4 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

What could I do better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Script needs to be run after dhcp is finished, most likely the module you want is dhcpcd. Another option would be to configure a static IP on your Pi.

Comment: To complete your answer: I put the code into `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/` as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/1005738